# How to connect to JIRA app on remote server from different local computers?

Tags: local-storage, jira, remote-access, remote-server

Is it possible to install JIRA on 2 local computers, then install it's database on a remote server, and connect these two computers with two different usernames to same project?

I have installed JIRA on these two local computers, then chose one of these computers as admin and created a new project with the database located on a remote server, but don't know how to create/add new user that other local computer can have access to this JIRA project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jira is a web service which when installed allows any computer within network reach to access this service through browser

Let's say you installed Jira on computer 1
You will be able to access Jira from computer 1's browser by the following url
http://localhost:8080 (if you used default settings during installation)

If you obtain computer 1 ip address, you may replace localhost with computer 1 ip.
Let's say computer 1 ip is 10.14.16.18
Open the following url from computer 1
http://[computer_1_ip]:8080

If computer 1 and 2 are on the same network and have no firewalls between them, you should be able to access Jira from computer 2 by using computer 1 ip:
http://[computer_1_ip]:[jira_port]

I hope this helps

Comment: I have 2 computers on my office, and installed JIRA on each of them locally. I also installed a PostgreSQL on our remote server and specified it's address when I installed JIRA on computer 1. But I didn't know how to configure computer 2 to connect to the JIRA and remote database and the project I created with computer 1.

Comment: May you explain what is the `[jira_port]` in this line ` http://[computer_1_ip]:[jira_port]`?
Why didn't you use `8080`?

Comment: There should be only one Jira installed on one computer and both computers should be using this Jira through browser

Comment: What URL do you use in browser to open Jira?

Comment: I put http://[computer_1_ip]:[jira_port] because during installation you may change the default port. I my self use use port 80. So i dont want to restrict my answer to port 8080

Comment: Since you installed Jira on computer 1 successfully, then let Jira run on computer 1 and let both computer 1 and 2 use it[

Comment: I use `localhost:8080` for opening JIRA.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214305/discussion-between-abdulkarim-and-user3486308).

Comment: OK, thank you  AbdulKarim, when the operatot of computer 2 comes to office I will try your suggestion and tell the result.